# Defining an instruction that accesses memory directly in GEM5 without accessing the caches

Tags: caching, memory-management, gem5

I am using GEM5 and I want to define an instruction that accesses memory without accessing the caches. I know how to add a new instruction and I was successful in adding it and running it with a sample C code. However, my instruction currently does not access memory. I want it to be similar to a load/store instruction but it will access memory directly without going to the caches. Is that possible in GEM5?

I have been reading about GEM5 for a couple of weeks and I could not figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create your own cache model as a wrapper to the cache model , check the opcode of your instruction so you can send to dram ..